# What is the best way to update the name of a Service?

Tags: services, macos

I changed the name of a Service by navigating to /Users/Me/Library/Services/ and renaming the .workflow file in Finder. I tried restarting the computer, but the previous Service name still exists in the menu bar and the context menu.

Is there something that I can do to force the computer to review the names of my Services?

Answer (score 4):

After renaming the .workflow file in Finder, open the file in Automator and then save the file (press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>). The file **must** be re-saved in Automator if you want the new name to appear in the menu bar and context menu.

Then, restart your computer.

By following these steps, I got my Service names to update.

Comment: So, did this and did the other answer THEN the names were corrected. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can try using lsregister:

```
/System/L*/Fr*/CoreS*/V*/A/F*/L*/V*/A/S*/lsregister -kill -seed -r -f -v -domain local -domain user -domain system
```

Comment: This did not work. The old Service name still exists in the menu bar and context menu.

Comment: Did this and the other answer THEN the names were updated, Thanks for this.